# component não renderiza no Angular

Tags: angular

Estou iniciando meus estudo no Angular e estou com uma dificuldade.

Tenho o meu app.component já criado e funcionando corretamente.

Criei um novo componente
ng generate component lista-pessoa e estou criando um input.

Dentro do arquivo lista-pessoa.component.ts eu crio uma variavel nome.

```
nome:   string  =   "Roseweltty";
```

Dentro do arquivo lista-pessoa.component.html eu crio o input.

```
<input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="nome">
```

// a variável nome ira exibir em tempo real as mudança feitas no input.

```
<p>{{nome}}</p
```

Quando mando abro o navegador não é exibido as informações do component lista-pessoa somente dos app.component, de modo que se eu colocar esses comandos no cs e html do app.component eles exibem na tela e mostra corretamente.

Minha pergunta é: há alguma configuração no Angular, VSCode etc, que tenho que fazer para exibir os componentes na aplicação corretamente? precisa ser feita alguma chamada para essas funções. ou algo do tipo. haja visto que não esta gerando erro nenhum, nem no console do browser nem no code.

Por favor preciso de uma ajuda, sei que deve ser somente um deslize meu, mais já pesquisei na net muito antes a ajuda do grupo.

Comment: Então você sabe que tem que declarar esse componente aonde quer exibi-lo?

Comment: Não sei não, como devo fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você ao criar um componente com Angular você automaticamente pode utilizá-lo onde precisar, para renderizar o novo componente em um outro é necessário declará-lo no componente pelo seu **[seletor](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#description)**:

> **Seu Componente ListaPessoa**

```
---------------- TS ----------------

imports {...} from '...'

@Component({
  selector: 'lista-pessoa',             <= seletor Html do componente
  ...
})

export class ListaPessoa implements OnInit {
  nome: string = "Roseweltty";      

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}

----------------- HTML ----------------

<div>
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nome">
</div>
```

> **Seu Componente AppComponent**

```
----------------- HTML ----------------

<div>
   <h1>Digite o seu nome:</h1>
   <lista-pessoa></lista-pessoa>        <= Utilizado aqui
</div>
```